# Accessing state inside a function in functional component

Tags: reactjs, function, events, react-hooks, assign

I'm creating socket io app, where I'm setting some value from incoming event using setState. I have two event handlers. One is to modify the value and second is supposed to read this value and eventually change it. Setting the value works well and it is rendered as expected. However, when I try to read the value from second handler, there is still initial one.

See below simplified code below.

```
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import {EventEmitter} from "events";

const NumComponent = () => {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(0)
    const emitter = new EventEmitter()
    const emitterRef = new useRef(emitter)

    useEffect(() => {
        emitterRef.current.on('setNum', () => setNum(10))
        emitterRef.current.on('readNum', () => console.log(num))
    }, [])

    return <div>
        {num}
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => emitterRef.current.emit('setNum')}>set num</button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button onClick={() => emitterRef.current.emit('readNum')}>read num</button>
        </div>
    </div>

}
export default NumComponent
```

How can I read the modified value from the second function?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to console.log(num) after the button onClick, initial render, or both?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't mention that. I want to first set the state by clicking on the first button and than be able to console.log the modified value by clicking the second button.

Comment: In that case why are you using a useEffect to begin with and not functions?

```
const handleSetNum = () => {
  emitterRef.current.on('setNum', () => setNum(10))
}
onClick={()=> handleSetNum}
```

Comment: I had issue with socket. Events were registered  multiple times as the component function was called.  Even on the example above, two values are printed after second button press without useEffect.